# How to determine the Ember route name from a URL?

Tags: ember.js

I need determine the route name from a URL string.

This is normally work that the Router does internally, but because of {insert long story here} I need to do it manually. I am given a piece of data from the API that looks like 'gallery/123' and I need to know the route name is 'gallery.post'. So that I can do `route.replaceWith(determinedRouteName);`

- Need to turn 'gallery/123' into 'gallery.post'
- Need to turn 'stuff/99/comments' into 'stuff.post.comments'
- Etc

Answer (score 0):

Ember relies internally to the [router-recognizer micro lib](https://github.com/tildeio/route-recognizer). I think that your best option is to use it as well.

Unfortunately, accessing the router instance is currently requiring to rely on the private `-routing` service. (Note: here is a [pending RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/95) about offering a public router service).

Injecting this private service:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  router: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),

  ...
});
```

The `recognize` function returns the list of all handlers that you can join if you want to build the complete string or anything else.

Ex:

```
this.router.recognize("stuffs/99/comments");
> [{handler: "application", ...}, 
    handler: "stuffs", ...}, 
    handler: "stuff", ...}, 
    handler: "comments", ...}, 
    handler: "comments.index, ...}]
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Are you going to always only have one ID in the route? Or will the first ID always be the 'post' ID at least? If so you this isn't really an Ember issue it would just be a JavaScript find/replace that always follows the same format assuming the API data always come back in the same format.

Assuming the API always provides this format:

"something/**:post_id**/optionally_something_else"

You could take the string that the API provided and run it through a couple replace methods:

```
var apiString = "stuff/99/comments";

apiString = apiString.replace(/[0-9]+/, "post").replace(/\//g, "."); // => "stuff.post.comments"

// Also works with:

var apiString = "gallery/123";

apiString = apiString.replace(/[0-9]+/, "post").replace(/\//g, "."); // => "gallery.post"
```

**DISCLAIMER:** This is pretty icky and will break if the string doesn't follow this format. It will also only covert the *first* set of digits to "post". But as usual, use it if you must :P